# Can i use ATmega8L instead of ATmega8?

Tags: robotics, atmega

I am recently doing a project on robotics.And am following (societyofrobots) 50$ robot tutorial for that purpose.But i can't find ATmega8 chip anywhere as they told but i did found atmega8L instead.Now,is it possible to replace atmega8 by atmega8L though it has low capacity than atmega8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Atmeega8L guaranteed to work at 8Mhz at 2.7V, 16Mhz operation at 4.5V is not guaranteed (but in practice it works).

Atmega8 guaranteed to work at 16Mhz at 4.5V.